# What is 侧面 doing in ...侧面反映了金融市场在入世以后逐渐与国际接轨?

Tags: meaning

I can't quite see what 侧面 is doing in this sentence; any tips please? I'll include the previous sentence for clarity.

> 今天，杨先生的银行存款很少，绝大部分都用来投资股市，一年下来，收益远远高出利息。
>
> 实际上，市民理财概念的变化，**侧面**反映了金融市场在入世以后逐渐与国际接轨。

Could I add 他的 or 市民的 or 杨先生的？  Such as in:

> 实际上，市民理财概念的变化，**他的侧面**反映了金融市场在入世以后逐渐与国际接轨。

where we have:

> **他的侧面**反映了金融市场在入世以后逐渐与国际接轨。
> his profile reflects the gradual integration of the (domestic) financial market into the international arena following China's entry into the WTO.

Or is that all wrong?

Comment: Just means something like indirectly

Answer (score 6):

In this sentence, 侧面 is not noun but adverb, 侧面反映 = *indirectly* reflected.

Comment: So it's 侧面地反映了。。。 ？？

Comment: @Pedroski yes...

Answer (score -1):

In this sentence:

> 实际上，市民理财概念的变化，侧面反映了金融市场在入世以后逐渐与国际接轨。

侧面 is used to `市民理财概念的变化`, the sentence can be:

`实际上，市民理财概念变化的侧面反映了金融市场在入世以后逐渐与国际接轨。`

It just say you can indicate something from something.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: In '概念变化的侧面反映了‘ what has '侧面‘ or '侧面反映‘ now become? A noun?

Comment: It becomes a adverb